# NetBeans HQL editor wrong translation to SQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, netbeans, hql, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to access a MySQL database from a Java webservice. I'm using the NetBeans IDE and am following the tutorial *[Using Hibernate in a Web Application](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html)*

Now when I try to test the [HQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29#Hibernate_Query_Language_.28HQL.29) query: from calls I get:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    blablabla
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from limit 100' at line 1
    bla, bla, bla
```

And the translated SQL is also wrong:

```
select  from
```

I created the calls.java class using Hibernate Reverse Engineering.

This is the `Hibernate.cfg.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datacheck</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">####</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I can't seem to find the error, and I searched the whole Internet :p

A similar thread is *[HQL Editor not appending table name in query](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic36999.html)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typed the HQL query

```
from call
```

while it should be:

```
from Call
```

with a capital first letter.

Dumb mistake, I thought it was the database table, but apparently it's the [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) name that you have to specify.