# NET BEANS HIBERNATE HQL QUERY EDITOR errors

Tags: hibernate

I recently tried a Hibernate Java swing sample on NetBeans 8.2 using this tutorial https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html. Complete project setting configuration and code has been done exactly as per tutorial using Hibernate 4.3X

When I right click on configuration file to open the HQL editor and type query in HQL window the following errors come up
If I use ASTQUERY it gives immediate error on SQL window "invalid query" even before you enter letter f of "from Film" and corresponding logged message is Film is not mapped.
If I switch to classic query it gives different error just by typing "from" corresponding SQL window message is "select from" and logged error is SQL syntax error
I checked all the old messages on this kind of problems and none of the solutions work or applicable to my case as follows

People reported noncompiling as one of the reason which is not the case here it is compiled and built successfully
People said Non capitalization of Class name but here " from Film" is used in the HQL query window
People said class is not mapped but is it mapped through hbm files
People said you have to give full pathname of class used
When I try query with path it gives 0 rows selected 0 rows updated message and SQL window is blank with out any translated code
Only 1 person got the same issue unsolved by all the above but no one gave effective solution
Did any one face same issue with NNET BEANS 8.2. When I tried with other example where query is executed through program instead of editor it works with correct output and correct SQL translation. So its not hibernate issue
It is related to NetBeans H"QL query editor only
Any thoughts why this happens while projected compiled successfully and all coding is exactly as per tutorial

Comment: Can you provide links to some of the other reports you're referencing?

Comment: One example link where such errors and possible solution discussed is https://coderanch.com/t/507908/databases/error-running-HQL-Query

Comment: Another  relevant example link while solution does not work for me is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570213/netbeans-hql-editor-wrong-translation-to-sql

Answer (score 1):

I found myself the  solution for this which is not  found anywhere on the forums. I got the answer when I down loaded existing NETBEANS HIBERNATE project into  D drive and ran it was running with out errors. Then I  coded the same project on NetBeans  but it was giving the  same error  showing the Class is not mapped.
Since my NETBEANS is installed  on C drive Program files it struck me that it is something to do with access rights. To check it I opened NETBEANS with administrator rights  and "viola" every project  was working fine with no errors
Then I went to  environmental variables and added the path to system variable for  netbeans64.exe. Thereafter  all NETBEANS HIBERNATE project worked   even with out opening ADMINTSRAYIVE rights
So you have to open NETBEANS with administrator access with out path specified in environment variable  for NETBEANS or you can add  path variable for netbeans.exe and open NETEANS with user rights and it will work beautifully with out errors